# How to prevent people from stealing my source code?

Tags: properties

I stuck searching of how people can get your source code and what they cab do with it once they get the access ?  And how i can protect it ? ( is this called lisense ?)

Answer (score 0):

You can use third-party services like [UglifyJS online](https://skalman.github.io/UglifyJS-online/).

Those services replace identifiers - like variable or function names - with some random, mostly short names. That way, a thief of your code is given a hard time to understand how your code works, rendering it basically useless for him.

You keep the readable code to yourself, and keep developing it. Once you want to publish a new version, you make a copy of your code, uglify it and upload it to your servers.

Your code will still work in the browser at all times.